# How to summarize events prior to a specific event (that can happen multiple times) across multiple observations in r?

Tags: r

I'm trying to collect data on what events have happened prior to a specific event (i.e. bDragons)which can be recurring based on the full observation. These are just an excerpt of one observation where a dragon is taken more than once, and I want to be able to pull insights on each and every one over many observations. So in the data set below, I would want to know that only 1 outer turret was taken prior to the first dragon at Time == 12.891. The next is taken at 20.215, which 4 towers and a drake before it.

```
 ID  TeamObj   Time       Type      Lane    League Year Season bResult rResult gamelength Gold
1  1  bTowers  9.397 OUTER_TURRET TOP_LANE  CBLoL 2017 Summer       1       0         34   NA
2  1  bDragons 12.891   AIR_DRAGON     <NA>  CBLoL 2017 Summer       1       0         34   NA
3  1  bTowers 16.215 OUTER_TURRET BOT_LANE  CBLoL 2017 Summer       1       0         34   NA
4  1  bTowers 16.591 INNER_TURRET BOT_LANE  CBLoL 2017 Summer       1       0         34   NA
5  1  bTowers 19.830 OUTER_TURRET MID_LANE  CBLoL 2017 Summer       1       0         34   NA
6  1  bDragons 20.215 EARTH_DRAGON     <NA>  CBLoL 2017 Summer       1       0         34   NA
7  1  bBarons 22.512 BARON_NASHOR     <NA>  CBLoL 2017 Summer       1       0         34   NA
8  1  bTowers 23.962 INNER_TURRET MID_LANE  CBLoL 2017 Summer       1       0         34   NA
9  1  bTowers 24.707 INNER_TURRET TOP_LANE  CBLoL 2017 Summer       1       0         34   NA
10 1  bTowers 24.962  BASE_TURRET TOP_LANE  CBLoL 2017 Summer       1       0         34   NA
```

I'd want this for every TeamObj of that type but the issue comes up where I try to `group_by` address and filter by `(Time <= which(Team == bDragons)`and the wrong things get filtered out or I can't summarize based on that `count(Type)` or anything. I'm looking for help on recording some type of recurring function or a better way to record and summarize that. Looking to fit the observations into a linear model later on, but I can't get to that square one which causes the issue.

Am I thinking about my filter incorrectly? My summarize? `tst3 %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Time <= which(Team == "bDragons")) %>% summarize(count(Type))`

Something like:

```
ID dragonID dragonType Time Baron_Nashor  Base_Turret  Inner_Turret  Nexus_Turret Outer_Turret
1 1 AIR_DRAGON 12.891 N/A N/A N/A N/A  1
2 2 EARTH_DRAGON 20.215 N/A N/A 1 N/A  3
```

and so on, if that is clear. Want to be able to use each as an observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following

```
tst3 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  # arrange(Time) %>% # uncomment if needed
  mutate(
    Type = factor(Type),
    dragonID = cumsum(dplyr::lag(TeamObj == 'bDragons', default = 1))) %>%
  group_by(ID, dragonID) %>%
  summarize(
    dragonType = last(Type),
    Time = last(Time),
    tmp =  list(as.data.frame(table(Type)))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  spread(Type, Freq, fill = 0) %>%
  # select(-ends_with("DRAGON")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(BARON_NASHOR:OUTER_TURRET), cumsum) %>%
  filter(str_detect( dragonType, "DRAGON"))
```

Comment: I'm going to try that right now, most of it makes sense. I'm curious as to why you would factor the ID's and the dragon_group though. Everything else makes sense though! I get that you want to add a column to mark each of the counts. An issue that comes up though is that the dragon_group is now going to mark a lot of various TeamObjs as their own line in dragon_group. It isn't consistent though...which is strange.

 i.e. the first few rows look like such: https://i.imgur.com/PtOZ2f0.png (mind ID is Address)

Comment: To further elaborate, it is adding a dragon_group number to every observation that does not have a dragon after it but shares the dragon_group number with the next observation if it IS a dragon. Trying to play around with it here.

Comment: the factors are a legacy from using `mutate_if(is.numeric, cumsum)` in an earlier version of this code.  when I added `Time`, in the `summarize` statement, it no longer became workable to handle it that way, but the factor statements remained.  They are not necessary.

Comment: If you want `dragon_group` to reset for each ID, just add a `group_by(ID)` at the beginning.

Comment: So the issue comes in where the dragon_group doesn't group each of the 
`TeamObj per dragon. When doing this though: tst3 %>%
    arrange(Address, Time) %>% 
    mutate(
        Address = factor(Id),
        dragon_group = factor(cumsum(TeamObj == 'bDragons'))) %>%
    group_by(Id, dragon_group) %>%
    summarize(
        Time = last(Time),
        tmp =  list(as.data.frame(table(Type)))) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    spread(Type, Freq) %>%
    select(-ends_with("DRAGON")) %>%
    group_by(Id)`
i get each group seperated per dragon, but can't cumsum properly. I also get an extra obs

Comment: should be fixed.

Comment: It fixed for the most part but the `mutate_at(vars(BARON_NASHOR:OUTER_TURRET), cumsum)` deletes the events between Baron_Nashor: Nexus_Turret. Before that the observations are shown though. I'm also still getting an extra observation on the groups where the last recorded TeamObj is not a dragon, can I filter those out somehow? I.e. in the first set, i get 4 dragons but there are only 3 taken and the last observation is a NEXUS_TURRET

Comment: `mutate_at` does not add or remove any variables.  The only place where I'm removing stuff is in the statement `select(-ends_with("DRAGON"))` - which removes columns associated with the dragons.  The filter statement is added.

Comment: What I'm saying is the mutate_at function is not a sum of all the variables, from BARON_NASHOR:NEXUS_TURRET all are N/A but if I look at the variables beforehand, they have values. It's kind of strange, it only not a cumulative sum on all variables. For instance, above, the inner turret happens at 16.591 but is counted as N/A throughout the function after the mutate_at area. When removed, there it no cumsum of course but it shows up as 1. What could potentially cause this? Trying to learn more as I just finished my R courses and this is a sticky situation for me

Comment: okay - when I read in your data, `Type` was read in as a factor.  I'm guessing you have it as a character.  This is causing the levels of each table to be different..  which is why I got the error and you did not.  There are 2 places you can fix this.  option1 - make `Type` a factor in the first `mutate` statement or option 2 - add `fill = 0` to the spread statement.  Either will solve the problem.

Comment: No need to add the na.rm I don't think but it works fine now! I thought fill would fix it but had to head onto the subway. Thank you so much, you figured it out!!!

Comment: Hi Mellisa, is there any way I can ask you a couple of more questions on adapting this a bit? I understand everything for the most part but am just looking to see if I can create a differential for each cummulative sum (so if there are two teams, seeing what the differential is between cumsum(OUTER_TURRET)). I can provide a sample data set and such